# Hard links with MergerFS

Tags: filesystems, hard-link, unionfs

If someone uses the command "cp -alr" on a directory located in a non-path preserving merged pool will it always create a directory on the same disk with all of its contents as hard links?

For example, if we created a merged pool with category.create=mfs and on the following directory tree we run "cp -alr /romance/TitanicMovie/ /comedy/" what would happen?

Would it create a directory on disk1 called comedy and a hard link to Titanic.mkv or because disk2 has more free space would it copy Titanic.mkv to the directory on disk2 called comedy?

```
 /mnt/
    ├── disk1/ (Physical Drive mounted,  1TiB in size)
    |   ├── romance/
    |   |   ├── TitanicMovie
    |   |       ├──Titanic.mkv
    ├── disk2/ (Physical Drive mounted,  1TiB in size)
    |   ├── comedy/
    ├── storage/ (mergerFS mounted using: /mnt/disk1:/mnt/disk2 /mnt/storage fuse.mergerfs dropcacheonclose=true,defaults,allow_other,minfreespace=50G,fsname=mergerFS,func.mkdir=all,category.create=mfs 0 0
    |   ├── romance/
    |   |   ├── TitanicMovie
    |   |       ├──Titanic.mkv
    |   ├── comedy/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific details on how `rename` and `link` work are in the [docs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#rename--link).

If you're **not** using path preservation then it clones the path on the same branch (if needed) and performs the rename or link.